# React app with the create react app commad. How do i include bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, frameworks

So i created a react app using the `create-react-app folder-name` from `cmd` 
 So how do i add bootstrap and other libraries to launch on npm start i.e. when i launch the app. Do i install them with bower install or with npm install. I am so new to this i don't even get how are all the scdripts from the framework are launching with idnex.html. I know that the question is probably somewhat retarded, but idk how to even ask it correctly.

Comment: You should have a package.json which lists all your packages installed. After that, you just have to import them into your .js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any libraries you want utilizing `npm` and [ES6 Import](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=es6%20import&oq=es6%20import&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2379j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
Just Import anything you want in `App.js`.
Here is step by step [guide](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-bootstrap) on adding bootstrap to your project.

Comment: npm install react-bootstrap --save isn't this the enitre react framework? cause i alrdy installed it create react app. And 1 more question " Import Bootstrap CSS and optionally Bootstrap theme CSS in the beginning of your `src/index.js` file:" Do i need to import this only in the index.js file?

Comment: Yes, if you need something global, like bootsrap css in your case you can import it once in `index.js`. However if you need to import some js library like `jQuery` for example, you should import it in any component that required it.

Comment: ok so doing npm install react-bootstrap --save after i did create react app is kinda of pointless? and basically all i can add is bootstraps css?

Comment: It depends on why do you need Bootstrap. If you need only css from it, than you can just import `bootstrap.css` file and then you can use all bootstarp classes, grids, etc.. but if you want js behavior of bootstrap elements like accordion or modal window, or dropdowns etc.. you should include `react-bootstrap` - it is a functional part of bootstrap framework but written as react components - you can check it here with code examples https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html